# Cpu Temperature on Windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, cpu, temperature

Is there a way to get the CPU temperature in windows 10? I tried to get it from the command line with wmic, but it always gives the same value. How can I do this without using a program? Or, is there an api that gives out the temperature information?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node JS, Read CPU temperature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47136213/node-js-read-cpu-temperature)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I tried this and the result is the same. I check the value in 1 second intervals. The temperature value stays at 27.8. Not updating.